# python error index out of bounds for .epw

Tags: python, bounds

I'm really new at python and I'm using a script to do some data analysis.
The analysis part is standard and in order to get results I need to import an .epw file.

```
nhours = 8760
n12h = 730
klimain = 'weather.epw'
data = readclimafile(klimain)
```

And I use the data array to do analysis. For example, I do this

```
def readradfile(radin):
rad = np.loadtxt(radin)
def do_analysis(t, rad):
R = 6.667
for j in range(rad.shape[0]):
            q[j] = (20-t[j])/R
```

So, when I use an .epw for a whole year it works fine.
But when I import an .epw for 8 days (192 hours), I get an error:

```
q[j] = (20-t[j])/R
IndexError: index 192 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 192
```

I changed the nhours to 191 and the n12h=16. I don't understand why it doesn't work. There's nowhere else to define the length of array, just the .epw imported. And it works fine for larger file, why does it get an error for a much smaller?
Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! 

This is very little code to go on. At least show where rad.shape is defined...

Comment: If there are 192 elements, and the first one is index 0, then the highest will be element 191.